# Import Javascript to Magento with addItem but with different type (text/babel)

Tags: javascript, xml, magento, layout, babeljs

I am trying to import a javascript file into my Magento theme with addItem, but to make it work in IE11 I want it to render as follows:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="js/my-file.js"></script>
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/my-file.js</name><params><![CDATA[type="text/babel"]]></params></action>
```

But no success... Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that without overriding/extending core head block (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php).

Here's the code snippet taken from the head block:

```
$html .= $this->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"%s></script>' . "\n",
    empty($items['js']) ? array() : $items['js'],
    empty($items['skin_js']) ? array() : $items['skin_js'],
    $shouldMergeJs ? array(Mage::getDesign(), 'getMergedJsUrl') : null
);
```

As you can see `type="text/javascript` is hardcoded.

My suggestion is to extend head block and implement new *item* types – `babel_js` and/or `babel_skin_js`. I choose this over changing `skin_js` / `js` types, in order to avoid any possible issue with 3rd party modules that might be used.

Best,
Mladen